# What kinds of objects is this Javascript creating?

Tags: javascript

I am scrambling to fix a production error and am **not** a JS developer. Before my analysis can go any further I need to be absolutely confident that I am making some correct assumptions about the following line of code:

```
var iVO = {
    "images":{}
};
var thisImage = $(this).data("data");

iVO["images"][thisImage.fileKey] = thisImage;
iVO["images"][thisImage.imageType] = imageType;
iVO["images"][thisImage.uploadReason] = uploadReason;
```

Here are my assumptions. If any are correct or misguided, please correct me:

- `iVO` is an array of JSON objects
- Each of these JSON objects is then given 3 properties (`fileKey`, `imageType` and `uploadReason`)

The thing that I don't get is the significance of the `"images"` index, What is the value/meaning of `iVO["images"]`? What does information/objects this first/outer array represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iVO` is an object literal. It functions like a hash.

`iVO["images"]` looks like array access, but in this case the code is accessing the `images` property on `iVO`.  In the end, it returns what `images` points at, which is `{}`, another object literal.

`var thisImage = $(this).data("data")` is using a jquery function.  [The documentation for jQuery.data is here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/).  `thisImage` is a reference to the data returned from the invocation of `data`

`iVO["images"][thisImage.fileKey] = thisImage;`

is just setting a value.  The first access is accessing the `images` property on `iVO`, which was a an object literal.  From that object literal, the code assigns the property `thisImage.fileKey` (whatever that is, it comes out of the data call on the previous line) the value of `thisImage`.

So, when you say

> iVO is an array of JSON objects

`iVO` is a **single** object literal, that contains another object literal under the `images` property.

**That** object literal has 3 values stuffed in it.  The keys (the named of the properties) depends on what the `data` call returned.  The values depend on `thisImage` (the result of the data call), and the variables `imageType`, and `uploadReason`.

You can use your debugger to step thru this code and see what the values are at each step.

Note JSON is not coming into play here.  From json.org, "JSON is a text format that is completely language independent...."

Comment: This may also help - the [MDC JavaScript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) about how to use objects.  It explains the different ways to access object properties (obj.prop and obj[prop]) which should help you better understand the code you're examining (because all your assumptions were wrong ;-))

Comment: Oh, and it should also be mentioned that line 2 (`"images": {}`) is creating an object so that the code later on can add properties to that object.  If you didn't have line 2, lines 6-8 would fail since `iVO["images"]` wouldn't be an object (undefined to be exact).

Answer (score 1):

`iVO` is an object.  This object has a property named `images` which is itself also an object.  This object has 3 properties, the names of which are contained in `thisImage`, the contents of which I cannot determine based on the code posted.

To answer your last question, `iVO["images"]` is equivalent to `iVO.images`.  It is the `images` property of `iVO`.